# Grails Multiples Database scheme structure update

Tags: database-design, grails, multi-tenant

how can we set up grails to do the update scheme structure to multiples databases in boostrap?

I'm using the multitenant core plugin in singleTenant mode and  by default he will only apply the new scheme structure to the default database.

i want to be able to apply the default structure database update to all databases at the same time on boostrap.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [TenantUtils](https://github.com/multi-tenant/grails-multi-tenant-core/blob/190bed38faa2b81074c7ce514e44e20243657e5e/src/groovy/grails/plugin/multitenant/core/util/TenantUtils.groovy) class for the plugin. You should be able to obtain a map of tenants using the getAllTenantData method then execute your code using the doWithTenant method for each tenant.